# Authentication failure! undefined method `values_at' for nil:NilClass: NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, devise, omniauth

I have rails 5 and ruby 2.7.
I want to integrate github login on my system
I have installed

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth-github'
gem "omniauth-rails_csrf_protection"
```

I did github config setting in `/config/initializers/devise.rb` file:

```
config.omniauth :github, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET_KEY'
```

When I am clicking on sign in with github it is showing below error:

```
 ERROR -- omniauth: (github) Authentication failure! undefined method `values_at' for nil:NilClass: NoMethodError, undefined method `values_at' for nil:NilClass
```

I have gone through the complete [documentaion](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview) of devise for omniauth documentation.
But, still I am getting this error.

I want the user should get logged in using github.

Comment: Can you post a full stack trace? Also can you post the class where you are calling `devise :omniauthable`?

Comment: Both, Rails 5 and Ruby 2.7, are outdated and reached end-of-live quite a while ago. What versions of the `devise` and the `omniauth-github` gem did you install? The documentation you were following might be for other versions than the version you installed.

Comment: This is my gemfile.lock versions:
`devise (4.9.3)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)`

    `omniauth (2.1.2)
      hashie (>= 3.4.6)
      rack (>= 2.2.3)
      rack-protection
    omniauth-github (2.0.1)
      omniauth (~> 2.0)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.8)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.8.0)
      oauth2 (>= 1.4, < 3)
      omniauth (~> 2.0)
    omniauth-rails_csrf_protection (1.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.2)
      omniauth (~> 2.0)`